# Object always in front of camera

Tags: three.js

On a `scene`, I've got a `camera` and an `obj`.

I want my `obj` always looks at the `camera`.

I tried with:

```
function render() {
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  var zCamVec = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1);
  camera.localToWorld(zCamVec);

  obj.lookAt(zCamVec);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

but without luck: my obj stays static...

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you right, the object needs to reposition in front of the camera, and look at the camera.

try this:

```
function render() {
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  var zCamVec = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1);
  var position = camera.localToWorld(zCamVec);

  obj.position.set(position.x, position.y, position.z);
  obj.lookAt(camera.position);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```